# How can I fix this JQuery function to obtain the data-value value of the parent li element of a clicked element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, jstree, jquery-events

I am not so into JavaScript and JQuery and I am finding the following difficulties.

Into a page there is redered a tree (using the JQuery **JStree* library).

So into my view code I have something like this representing a node of this tree:

```
<li role="treeitem" data-jstree="{&quot;opened&quot;:true,&quot;selected&quot;:true,&quot;icon&quot;:&quot;/_layouts/15/images/ArxeiaProtocollo/Default/Titolario/tag.png&quot;}" data-id="1" data-value="6.1" aria-selected="true" aria-level="3" aria-labelledby="j1_5_anchor" aria-expanded="true" id="j1_5" class="jstree-node  jstree-open">
    <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"/>
    <a class="jstree-anchor  jstree-clicked" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="j1_5_anchor">
        <i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon jstree-themeicon-custom" role="presentation" style="background-image: url(&quot;/_layouts/15/images/ArxeiaProtocollo/Default/Titolario/tag.png&quot;); background-position: center center; background-size: auto;"/>6.1 - Listino Prezzi</a>
    <ul role="group" class="jstree-children">
        <li role="treeitem" data-jstree="{&quot;opened&quot;:false,&quot;icon&quot;:&quot;/_layouts/15/images/ArxeiaProtocollo/Default/Titolario/tag.png&quot;}" data-id="1" data-value="6.1.1" aria-selected="false" aria-level="4" aria-labelledby="j1_6_anchor" id="j1_6" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf">
            <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"/>
            <a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="j1_6_anchor">
                <i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon jstree-themeicon-custom" role="presentation" style="background-image: url(&quot;/_layouts/15/images/ArxeiaProtocollo/Default/Titolario/tag.png&quot;); background-position: center center; background-size: auto;"/>6.1.1 - Acquisti - AAA</a>
        </li>
        <li role="treeitem" data-jstree="{&quot;opened&quot;:false,&quot;icon&quot;:&quot;/_layouts/15/images/ArxeiaProtocollo/Default/Titolario/tag.png&quot;}" data-id="0" data-value="6.1.0" aria-selected="false" aria-level="4" aria-labelledby="j1_7_anchor" id="j1_7" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf jstree-last">
            <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"/>
            <a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="j1_7_anchor">
                <i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon jstree-themeicon-custom" role="presentation" style="background-image: url(&quot;/_layouts/15/images/ArxeiaProtocollo/Default/Titolario/tag.png&quot;); background-position: center center; background-size: auto;"/>6.1.0 - Acquisti - ZZZ</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

So this is the script that render the tree using the JSTree JQuery library (it works perfectly fine):

```
<script>
$(function () { 
    $(#tree).jstree(
    { 
        "search" : { 
            "show_only_matches" : false 
        },        
        "plugins" : ["search"] 
    }
}).delegate("a", "click", function (event, data) {
    var pNode = event.target.parentNode.innerText;
    pNode = pNode.split(" - ")[0];

    // MY NEW CODE START
    var pNodeDataValue = event.target.parentNode.data('value');
    alert(pNodeDataValue);
    // MY NEW CODE END

    window.location.replace('" + link + "' + pNode); });
    var to = false; 
    $('#tree_q').keyup(function () { 
        if(to) { clearTimeout(to); } 
        to = setTimeout(function () { 
            var v = $('#tree_q').val(); 
            $('#tree').jstree(true).search(v); 
        }, 250); 
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

As you can see this code contains also a **delegate** defining a function that handles the click on a specific tree node and here I am finding some difficulties trying to implement a litle change on the original logic.

The original logic that I am trying to change is the following one: clicking on a node should mean click on the  element in the previous HTML code. So clicking on the an  element it retrieve

```
var pNode = event.target.parentNode.innerText;
pNode = pNode.split(" - ")[0];
```

This code should do the following operation:

obtain the content of the clicked element and put it into the **pNode** variable. So **pNode** will contains something like this: **6.1 - Listino Prezzi** (referring to the previous HTML code example), then split and put into **pNode** only the **6.1** value.

Ok it works fine but since I have to remove this index number (6.1 ans similar) from my tree visualization I have to obtain this value from somewhere else.

So I know that the **data-value** field of the parent 



 element. Infact as you can see in the previous HTML example code I have something like:

```
<li role="treeitem" data-jstree="{&quot;opened&quot;:true,&quot;selected&quot;:true,&quot;icon&quot;:&quot;/_layouts/15/images/ArxeiaProtocollo/Default/Titolario/tag.png&quot;}" data-id="1" data-value="6.1" aria-selected="true" aria-level="3" aria-labelledby="j1_5_anchor" aria-expanded="true" id="j1_5" class="jstree-node  jstree-open">
```

As you can see there is **data-value="6.1"** and it is the value that I have to retrieve and then use in my function.

As you can see into my previous JQuery code I tried to obtain it in this way:

```
// MY NEW CODE START
var pNodeDataValue = event.target.parentNode.data('value');
alert(pNodeDataValue);
// MY NEW CODE END
```

but it is not working and in the console of my browser I am obtaining the following error message executing this line:

```
TypeError: event.target.parentNode.data is not a function
```

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I try to fix this issue and obtain the value of the value of the **data-value** of the parent 



 element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use jQuery function `data()` on the DOM-object, which doesn't have such method.

Use instead:

`var pNodeDataValue = event.target.parentNode.dataset.value;`

or

`var pNodeDataValue = $(event.target).parent().data('value');`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are mixing jQuery and plain javascript in the same code. The [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) function, for example, it only works with jQuery selectors.

---

First of all, let's choose the selector.
With jQuery you have some ways to do so:

1. Using the plain javascript you were using as reference: `$(event.target.parentNode)`
2. Using `this` to not rerun the DOM query, and adding the [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/): `$(this).parent()`;
3. Using the plain javascript with [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/): `$(event.target).parent()`
4. Using `this.parentNode` as reference: `$(this.parentNode)`

---

Now, about getting the attribute `data-value`, with jQuery references, you can use these methods:

1. Using [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) to get `data-*` attributes: `$(this).parent().data('value')`
2. Using [`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get any attribute: `$(this).parent().attr('data-value')`

But, if you realy want to use plain javascript references (I don't recommend it, since you already have jQuery), you can use javascript [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute): `event.target.parentNode.getAttribute('data-value')`

---

Snippet with examples:

```js
$("#clickable").on("click", function(event, data){
  console.log("With jQuery: ",
  
  "\n$(event.target.parentNode).data('value') :",
  $(event.target.parentNode).data('value'),
  
  "\n$(this.parentNode).data('value') :",
  $(this.parentNode).data('value'),
  
  "\n$(event.target).parent().data('value') :",
  $(event.target).parent().data('value'),
  
  "\n$(this).parent().data('value') :",
  $(this).parent().data('value'),
  
  "\n$(this).parent().attr('data-value') :",
  $(this).parent().attr('data-value'),
  
  "\n\nWith plain Javascript:",
  "\nthis.parentNode.getAttribute('data-value')",
  this.parentNode.getAttribute('data-value'),
  
  "\nevent.target.parentNode.getAttribute('data-value') :",
  event.target.parentNode.getAttribute('data-value'));
});
```

```css
#clickable {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: blue;
  width: ;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="parent" data-value="datavalue">
  <div id="clickable">
    Click me!
  </div>
</div>
```